# Issue with zabbix server

Tags: zabbix

I have the problems with my zabbix server. 
The percent of busy configuration syncer processes are growth to 100%, and in result my server not respond sometimes.

Can some one help with it? logs are clear. Example my config :

```
LogFile=/opt/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
AlertScriptsPath=/etc/zabbix/alertscripts
DBHost=host
DBName=zabbix
DBUser=zabbix
DBPassword=zabbix
StartPollers=500
StartPollersUnreachable=100
StartPingers=10
StartDiscoverers=5
StartHTTPPollers=10
CacheSize=1G
HistoryCacheSize=1G
TrendCacheSize=256M
HistoryTextCacheSize=256M
Timeout=30
JavaGateway=host
JavaGatewayPort=10052
StartJavaPollers=50
StartTrappers=50
```

Comment: According to settings like StartPollers=500 and StartJavaPollers=50, you have a pretty big installation. However, there is only one configuration syncer process and that cannot be changed. If you enable DebugLevel=4 for that process or do strace on it, what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Raise the number of Db Syncer
Example

```
StartDBSyncers=20
```

And decrease the timeout

```
Timeout=7
```